# Amazon S3 object lifecycle configuration rule based on date

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

From the [Amazon S3 developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-dg.pdf):

> When using the Transition and Expiration actions, you can specify a
>   date when the action will be taken.

I saw a lot of example rules based on object age in the guide but I could not find any example that uses the date so I am a bit confused about the exact XML element to use and the date format.

I guess it would be something like:

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <ID>Archive All Object After a Week</ID>
        <Prefix></Prefix>
        <Status>Enabled</Status>
        <Transition>
            <Date>2016/08/11</Date>
            <StorageClass>GLACIER</StorageClass>
        </Transition>
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

Anyone can throw some light on this?

Comment: this is set for the s3 bucket not the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set this via the AWS console, you need to do it via the API. you can figure out the XML by looking at the "PUT bucket lifecycle policy" api call:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html

You can see the elements that are required and valid values.

> The date value must conform to the ISO 8601 format. The time is always
>   midnight UTC.